# How to add a play again button in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making Space Invaders using python.
I just want to add a button so that the player can start the game over again.

Here is my code

```py
import math
import random
 
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
 
pygame.init()
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
 
background = pygame.image.load('background.png')
 
 
mixer.music.load("background.wav")
mixer.music.play(-1)
 
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader - Made by Ishan Ahuja")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
 
playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0
 
 
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6
 
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('enemy.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 736))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(4)
    enemyY_change.append(40)
 
bulletImg = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 10
bullet_state = "ready"
 
 
score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
 
textX = 10
testY = 10
 
over_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)
 
 
def show_score(x, y):
    score = font.render("Score : " + str(score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))
 
 
def game_over_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(over_text, (200, 250))
 
 
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))
 
 
def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))
 
 
def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))
 
 
def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False
 
running = True
while running:
 
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    bulletSound = mixer.Sound("laser.wav")
                    bulletSound.play()
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0
 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0
 
    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736
 
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
 
        if enemyY[i] > 440:
            for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                enemyY[j] = 2000
            game_over_text()
            break
 
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 4
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >= 736:
            enemyX_change[i] = -4
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
 
        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            explosionSound = mixer.Sound("explosion.wav")
            explosionSound.play()
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = "ready"
            score_value += 1
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)
 
        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)
 
    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"
 
    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change
 
    player(playerX, playerY)
    show_score(textX, testY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: what did you try? You will have to create button on your own. And you can put `while running` inside `while repeating` to repeate all again.

Comment: You have to add the relevant code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

For that put your game code in a function example main(). So that you can call it again and again!

Like don't put the `enemyImg = []`,
`enemyX = []`,
`enemyY = []`,
`enemyX_change = []`,
`enemyY_change = []`,
`num_of_enemies = 6` in the main() function. It's your choice. But put the things in main() function and when game is over you can call it again! Hope it works.